# openshift rhc you do not have git installed

Tags: openshift-client-tools

I am trying to setup the rhc client for openshift. I followed the tutorial precisely. After installing ruby, git and the rhc gem, the setup went perfect. But it wont clone my app to my computer. When I type rhc git-clone it says that git is not installed, but git --version works fine.

Comment: I think some more details could help others help you. Is this (https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-windows.html#installing-git) the tutorial you have followed? What is the installed git & ruby version? Alternatively, as the git itself seems to be working fine, you can also do `git clone ssh://xxx@<appname>-<domainname>.rhcloud.com/~/git/<appname>.git/` instead of using `rhc clone`.

Comment: I spend like 4 hour on this and tried different computers all with the same problem. Tried every version of ruby on the download page and several of  git. The problem was the default install folder. rhc coouldn't find git. Maybe someone should edit the rhc code? The default install folder is different in newer versions of git.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, git installs itself default in users\\appdata\local\Git . I read somewhere that you shouldn't mess with the folder. But older versions installed in program files. So i tried that and rhc found it immediatly.

So just install git in  C:\Program Files\Git

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional piece of information to RiverWalker's self answer: run the git install as 'administrator'. Then "C:\Program Files\Git" directory will be used as the default installation dir.